# how to detect two or more circles overlaped on google map

Tags: math, google-maps-api-3, physics

I have random markers (vector circles) on random coordinates. If I have the radius of circles, then how I could find that two or more circles has overlapped or not?

Do you have any idea about `zoom` level also? In different zoom levels, circles may overlap or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the distance between the centers of the circles is less than the sum of the two radii, then they overlap.  Zoom is not relevant if you are working in real distances.

Comment: Thanks man, no, it's not a real distance when you're gonna show that on the map, it's pixels, huh? how do I calculate the center-to-center distance when I have Lan-Long values? I mean these are degrees ...

Comment: You tagged this google-maps-api-3; circles in that API are defined by a center coordinate (latitude/longitude) and a radius (in real distance).  Please update your question with the details (or at least more specifics) if you are not using google maps api v3 circles.

Comment: No, I'm using google maps API, I meant that two circles might not overlaps when you zoom-in, but with initial zoom their are overlapped. In a real distance they are not overlapped also, but as google maps shown them in a pixel-basis (they are vector, showing off on a screen), then they are overlapped. I hope you understand me better now ...

Comment: thanks for the explanation, actually I'd try another approach, however I'd accept your answer as it is right and seems I've problems in my question. Thank you again! :)